# What is wrong with this XML code? - Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, debugging

I created a soundboard with 200 Sounds and a BottomNavigationBar.
On some devices like the Huawei P8 Lite and the Samsung galaxy s7 it looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/2a08bcd731fb1cfeb07e72f75bc05e7e

And on my nox player and bluestacks it looks like this:
https://gyazo.com/e26327d7ba0ed366f15c61bd3130ae39

Here is the XML code with only 2 colums and 3 rows just to keep it in summery (Normaly there are 100 rows)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button1"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Button1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button2"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"                       
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button2"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button3"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button3"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button3"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button4"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button3"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button4"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button5"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button5"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button5"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button6"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:onClick="Button6"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Button6"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

    </GridLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

On Devices with Android 6 its working perfekt, but on Devices with Android 4 its showing nothing.

How can I solve this error? I want that the App is available on every device from Android 4.

Warning!This is not to be an advertising but it would realy help if you could tell me if this error occurs. 
Googe Play: Gronkh Soundboard
Please download and tell me if the error accours, please write your version with it.
After that you can uninstall the app.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aaron.waller.gronkhsoundboard

Comment: That is just horrible design.  Dump the GridLayout, and learn to use GridView or RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tr this code. I have removed some attributes which is i don't think required. Hope it will help

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="Button1"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="Button1"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

        ...

    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```